# How do I convert TotalPhysicalMemory to GB in Get-CimInstance with 2-3 lines?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to get computers name,  model, manufacturer and RAM size with Get-CimInstance and format it to a table later on without the TotalMemorySize and only my RAM tableslot.
What I'm stuck with is converting the bytes to GB:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Name, Manufacturer, Model, TotalPhysicalMemory,
@{
    Name = "RAM"
    Expression = {
        'GB'  ([math]::[int](TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
        }
Format-Table *
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Since you're using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) with a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as its `Expression` entry value, you must use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the input object at hand; thus `$_.TotalPhysicalMemory` retrieves the (current) pipeline input object's `.TotalPhyicalMemory` property value.
- PowerShell supports [binary multiplier suffixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Numeric_Literals?view=powershell-7.4#integer-literals) in number literals, so that you can use `1gb` for 1 [gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) (`[Math]::Pow(1024, 3)`), for instance.
- To concatenate strings in PowerShell, you need the `+` operator (with a string as the LHS). However, for more sophisticated string formatting, you can use `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f); `{0}` refers to the first RHS operand, and `{0:F0}` formats it as a floating-point number (`F`) with `0` decimal places, which effectively rounds it to an *integer*.

To put it all together:

```bash
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | 
  Select-Object Name, Manufacturer, Model, TotalPhysicalMemory, @{
    Name = 'RAM'
    Expression = { '{0:F0}GB' -f ($_.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1gb) }
  } |
  Format-Table # format as table *for display only*
```